# deprecated error in LUWIT

Tags: java-me, deprecated, lwuit

> The method
>   CommandListener(ActionListener) from
>   the type Form is deprecated.

the above error started coming when I imported this.

> import com.sun.lwuit.Form;
>
> Form f = new Form("Hello, LWUIT!");
>
> f.show();
>   f.setCommandListener(this); //error in this line.

Comment: Have you implemented the listener properly???

Comment: What problem you are facing? tell me clearly. have you implement ActionListener? try to post your code properly.

Answer (score 2):

Deprecation is a warning not an error and it usually includes an explanation of why it is happening. In this particular case the setCommandListener API was replaced with an add/removeCommandListener API to allow multiple listeners per form.
In the upcoming LWUIT version setCommandListener will no longer exist (just replace it with addCommandListener).